# What does $x*$ mean?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I am trying to understand what the operator $*$ means in Boolean algebra. If x is a Boolean variable, what does the expression $x*$ mean?

Comment: Is it $x*$, or $x*y$? And are you sure that the symbol looks like $*$, or are you talking about multiplication?

Comment: It is $x*$ not $x*y$. That is, it is a unary operator. It is from the book, "Discrete Mathematics and its Application" by Kenneth Rosen. It is used in one of the exercises. I could believe that it is a typo but I think not.

Comment: Well, if it's used in an exercise, the symbol will have been introduced somewhere.

Comment: I have that book but do not find the $ x*$ expression in the chapter dealing with Boolean algebra. Could you specify the page?

Comment: Look on page 39 which is section 1.3 There are exercises for the reader to do. Look at exercise numbers. Look at exercises 40 and 41. You will see $s*$ used where s is a Boolean variable / compound proposition.

Comment: You might want to include a screen shot or update the question with the specific text.

Comment: Could it be that the author uses $*$ for the complement, as $x^*$? I've seen that before.

Comment: @amrsa It could be the complement. I am not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In these exercises, $s*$ means the dual of $s.$  This is obtained from $s$ (which is an expression of propositional calculus containing only the operations $\wedge, \vee,$ and $\neg$) by replacing $\wedge$ with $\vee$, $\vee$ with $\wedge$, $T$ with $F$, and $F$ with $T$.

In the edition of the book I looked at, the author defines *dual* just before exercise 34, a few exercises above the one the OP referenced in a comment.